Mongodb version 6.4 of node-mongodb-native driver is having read ECONNRESET
node version: 20.11.1
We are using MongoClient to connect to the Azure AKS pod in a cluster that has mongodb server mongo:6.0 image deployed. We are using connection pools and application wide single connection. We are using following object for making connections,
const URL = `mongodb://db1.domain.com,db2.domain.com,db3.domain.com`;
const _mongodb = new MongoClient(URL, {
      retryWrites: true,
      w: 'majority',
      replicaSet: 'rs0',
      auth: {
        username: process.env.MONGODB_USER,
        password: process.env.MONGODB_PASS
      },
      tls: true,
      tlsCertificateKeyFile: "file for tls certificate key",
      tlsCAFile: "certificate file here"
      retryReads: true,
      retryWrites: true,
      socketTimeoutMS: 0,
      connectTimeoutMS: 0,
      monitorCommands: true,
      heartbeatFrequencyMS: 1000,
      localThresholdMS: 1000,
      maxPoolSize: 100,
    });
  }
    console.log(`Attempting to connect to MongoDB: ${URL}`);
    const start = new Date();
    const client = await _mongodb.connect();
    const durationMs = new Date().valueOf() - start.valueOf();
    _database = _mongodb.db("v1"); //database version 1 in use
    const MONGO_CLIENT_EVENTS = [ "connectionClosed",  "error", "timeout", "close"];
    //Adding connection closed event listners
    MONGO_CLIENT_EVENTS.forEach(event => {
      client.on(event, (e) => {
        console.log('event', e);
      })
    });

Our application does thousands of database operations. The connection and the database operations are successful and works in production environment.
When we upgraded the mongodb npm package that we use for database to version 6.4, the following error is coming up randomly.
MongoNetworkError: read ECONNRESET 

    at connectionFailureError (C:\app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:357:20) 

    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\app\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:268:44) 

    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:633:26) 

    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28) 

    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8) 

    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3) 

    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) { 

  connectionGeneration: 2, 

  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }, 

  [cause]: Error: read ECONNRESET 

      at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) { 

    errno: -4077, 

    code: 'ECONNRESET', 

    syscall: 'read' 

  } 

} 

We have set the socketTimeoutMS: 0, and connectTimeoutMS: 0. So the socket won't have timeout but the error indicates that mongodb connection is timed out.
This issue only occurs in mongodb Node.Js 6.0 and above.
Does anyone know about this issue/fixes?
We have tries to tune the connection options, 
      retryReads: true,
      retryWrites: true,
      socketTimeoutMS: 0,
      connectTimeoutMS: 0,
      monitorCommands: true,
      heartbeatFrequencyMS: 1000,
      localThresholdMS: 1000,
      maxPoolSize: 100

We were expecting that we won't see any MongoNetworkError: read ECONNRESET errors coming from mongodb when we upgrade the driver from 5.3 to 6.4.
